# upgrade php via .htaccess wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a WordPress site hosted on speicherzentrum.de. My current PHP version is 5.6.29. I would like to update it to 7.2. unfortunately, the webhoster doesn't have c-panel access to change the PHP version and I'm trying to do it by changing the .thaccess file.

the current .haccess contains following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<FilesMatch "xmlrpc\.php$">
Satisfy Any
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

So I tried to change it to :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<FilesMatch "xmlrpc\.php$">
Satisfy Any
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php72 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

But the PHP version did not change.
I also tired `.../x-httpd-php7 .php...`
But didn't work either. Any suggestions, how I could update my PHP version by editing the .htaccess file?

Comment: Depends on how PHP is configured on that webhost. There's various ways to set it up, such as [ProxyPassMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch). Consult your provider for details.

Comment: Changing the handler only applies if your hosting company has multiple versions of php installed in parallel.  In most cases, your host will need to recompile your hosting environment to do this which means you need to call them and have them do this for you.